# using dynamic IN clause in MSSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Why the following SQL does not fetch me anything

```
DECLARE @Status AS VARCHAR(400)
SET @status = '''Closed'',''OPEN'''
select * from MYTABLE where status in(@status)
```

While as 
`select * from MYTABLE where status in('Closed','Open')` fetches me rows

Comment: i did check, but all of them were related to LINQ. Sorry if i missed any, could you please point me to a similar post

Comment: Check this link might help. Yeah, you are right. It seems difficult to find one, but I am sure there are lots. Anyway got one link tough - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194120/formatting-a-string-for-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can if you want do some dynamic SQL but I think it is not really competitive..

```
  DECLARE   @Status nVARCHAR(400),
            @SQL nvarchar(500)

SET @status = '''Closed'''+','+'''OPEN'''
set @SQL = '
select * from [MYTABLE] where status in('+@status +')'

 exec sp_executesql @SQL
GO
```

Comment: Happy to help but take care of SQL injection with dynamic SQL if is the code for webApp..

Answer (score 4):

Your first question checks if the value `'Closed','OPEN'` exists in the database. The values is not expanded.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or later you can use [Table Valued Parameters](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, never knew that. Helped me understand the problem